# change keyboard layout in console

Tags: keyboard

I want to change the keyboard to us in the console.

I am able to change the layout in the startx environment via

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

but it doesn't change in the console. If I use startx and then use the lxterminal the keyboard switched to us, but after reboot to the console it doesn't.

I also changed the default file via:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

and changed the gb to us.

All in all if I am in the startx environment it works in the console it doesn't. Even when it has worked in the startx environment and then logoff to the console the keyboard switches back to gb.

Hope someone can help me, I googled and had a look on other sites but couldn't change the problem.

I tried it with 2 different keyboards, both from Dell but I think it shouldn't be a fault caused by the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not physical keyboard issue, but system problem. Have a look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console#Setting_keyboard_layout)

Comment: thx I will have a look at it

Comment: Thats a link only answer. Can you expand the answer to include the essential information form the link?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming Raspbian:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then go to **4 Internationalisation Options**, then **I3 Change Keyboard Layout**. Select a US keyboard layout, and you should be up and running.

Comment: As I have written in my question I already did this. My command is just the shortcut of your answer. But thx anyway

Comment: Not exactly; raspi-config calls `invoke-rc.d keyboard-setup start` after dpkg-reconfigure, which is a little more than just editing /etc/default/keyboard …

Comment: `sudo raspi-config`, changing settings plus reboot did the job just fine for me. Reference: [Keyboard layout for Your country](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=18906)

Answer (score 2):

For me this final working solution was:

`sudo raspi-config`

"Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)" has slightly different menu items names(compared to the previous reply) in "raspi-config" dialog:

- -> 4 **Localisation Options** -> I3 **Change Keyboard Layout**

Also you need to choose your second language (e.g. Russian) as keyboard layout, then setup other options and finish configuration. All changes will be applied immediately.

After this your /etc/default/keyboard file will look like

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard

# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:caps_toggle,grp:lwin_switch,compose:ralt,terminate:ctrl_alt_bks$

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

---

Before this I've tried 2 other ways:

1. manually configure locales using `sudo cat /etc/default/keyboard` + reboot
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` + reboot

Both methods didn't enable local switching shortcuts.

---

P.S: Also you can manually edit `/etc/default/keyboard` file than launch **raspi-config**

Comment: In my kernel version raspi-config has no Internationalisation Options and no I3 in Localisation Options. But editing sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard XKBLAYOUT and setting it to "de" worked