# Keyboard Layout for Login Screen

Tags: keyboard, login

How do I change the keyboard layout for the Raspberry PI login screen?

After booting Raspbian, I changed the keyboard layout to Programmer's Dvorak and updated my password. Then I updated my shell to ZSH and logged out to see the changes take effect.

When I get to the login screen, I see that the keyboard defaults back to USA. [facepalm]

Unfortunately my password is long, and I don't want to have to learn to type it in another layout. Is there a way to change the keyboard layout for the Login screen?

Comment: Tried `sudo raspi-config` yet?

Comment: Although it's not substantial to your question, it might be worth noting that there are US, UK, etc. versions of a Dvorak keyboard, so the default you are referring to here isn't what you think it is (presumably you mean qwerty, or "standard 104-key PC", etc).  The initial default on Raspbian is actually a *UK* keyboard (which isn't about layout so much as it is the content of a few particular keys).  As Kong Chun Ho implies, you haven't said *how* you changed the keyboard layout, which makes it more difficult to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Also worth noting, if the change is something that you expected to affect a *login session* or a *particular user's configuration* -- saying "logged out to see the changes take effect" implies that -- they of course it won't apply to the login screen, because that user is not logged in.  If the change is something that is supposed to apply to the system as a whole, I believe changing the keyboard may requires a reboot (although unplugging it and plugging it back in may also work, I'm not sure).

Comment: I ended up uninstalling the GUI anyway and just using `sudo raspi-config` as Kong Chun Ho suggested. It is nice that RP3 comes with Programmers Dvorak out of the box. Installing it on the original PI was quite a process!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change keyboard layout in console](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24161/change-keyboard-layout-in-console)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that changing the keyboard layout in `sudo raspi-config` > `Localisation Options` > `Change keyboard layout` works for the login screen. Just did it. Bothers me to have to figure out my password in QWERTY too.

[raspi-config - Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md)